# Attempting an hbase bulkloading job, the reducer uses a bloom filter that complains about unordered input

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm doing a large scale hbase import using a map-reduce job I set up like so.

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
job.setMapperClass(BulkMapper.class);

job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(inputPath));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);  //This creates a text file that will be full of put statements, should take 10 minutes or so
boolean suc = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

It uses a mapper that I make myself and HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad sets up a reducer.  I've done proofs of concepts with this setup before, however when I ran it on a large dataset it died in the reducer with this error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Non-increasing Bloom keys: BLMX2014-02-03nullAdded after BLMX2014-02-03nullRemoved at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.appendGeneralBloomfilter(StoreFile.java:934) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.append(StoreFile.java:970) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:168) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat$1.write(HFileOutputFormat.java:124) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:576) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer.reduce(PutSortReducer.java:78) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer.reduce(PutSortReducer.java:43) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:645) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:405) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157) Container killed by the ApplicationMaster. Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
```

I thought hadoop was supposed to guarantee sorted input into the reducer, if so why am I having this issue and is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm deeply annoyed that this worked, the problem was in the way I was keying my map output.  I replaced what I used to have for output with this:

```
ImmutableBytesWritable HKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable(put.getRow());
context.write(HKey, put);
```

Basically the key I was using and the key to the put statement were slightly different which cause the reducer to receive put statements out of order.